# how to display attributes of logged in user in yii

Tags: yii, model, attributes

I want to check if what I was doing was right so I have this code...

```
$user= Yii::app()->user->id;
$account= $user->account_type;
print_r($account);
```

My table has the following attributes: `account_id`, `username`, `password` and `account_type`

but when I do the code... I get the following error:

> "Trying to get property of non object"

please help, I am a beginner so I'm sorry for a basic problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a model for your table using `gii`, and then query the model using the user `id`, something like:

```
$user= Yii::app()->user->id;
$userModel = User::model()->findByPK($user);
$account= $userModel->account_type;
```

or, you can `setState` in your `UserIdentity.php` after validating username and password, like:

```
$this->setState('accounttype', $userModel->account_type);
```

and use this wherever you want just like:

```
echo Yii::app()->user->accounttype
```

You can check this [yii wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/)

Hope that helps :)